# Is there better documentation on Apples UTI system?

Tags: cocoa, uti

I have a Cocoa document-based application that works fine. However, when I create a UTI for the document and export it, my application can neither read, write or create its own files (or any others). It has only a menu. No logs, nothing.

Is the Cocoa NSDocument system really that broken?

Answer (score 0):

No, the `NSDocument` system is not that broken. You have a bug. The most likely cause is that you have corrupted your `Info.plist`. Without some hints about what you've actually done it's difficult to be certain, but that's the most likely. You can use `plutil -lint <file>` to make sure you haven't broken that.

Beyond that, of course, try removing the UTI and see if the problem goes away. If so, then you are likely adding the UTI incorrectly and with details, we may be able to help. If the problem doesn't go away, you broke something else that you didn't realize you touched.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thanks. I was tired and my document code was testing for the old document type. My bad.